# Is there a way to filter a file for lines that only occur once, based on a field?

Tags: bash, awk, gnu, uniq

I have a "diff like" file where the fields are separated by tabs. Is there a way to get only the lines that are present once, using only standard gnu tools, where two lines are equal if their second field is equal?

Essentially, I want to filter this file for only new lines and deleted lines, not edited lines.

The file is sorted first by the second column (name) then by the first column (subtractions then additions).

```
<   Chandler Hutchison  Chicago Bulls   Wed, Oct 30, 2019   Out (Hamstring) - The Bulls have listed Hutchison as OUT for Wednesday's (Oct. 30) game against the Cavs.
>   Chandler Hutchison  Chicago Bulls   Thu, Oct 31, 2019   Out (Hamstring) - The Bulls have listed Hutchison as OUT for Friday's (Nov. 1) game.
>   Daniel Theis    Boston Celtics  Thu, Oct 31, 2019   Day To Day (Left Ankle) - Boston Celtics F-C Daniel Theis is probable for Friday's (Nov. 1) game against New York right a left ankle sprain.
<   Edmond Sumner   Indiana Pacers  Wed, Oct 30, 2019   Day To Day (Hand) - Sumner is OUT for Wednesday's game (Oct. 30) against the Nets.
>   Edmond Sumner   Indiana Pacers  Thu, Oct 31, 2019   Out (Hand) - Sumner will miss at least three weeks with a non-displaced fracture in his right hand.
<   Elfrid Payton   New York Knicks Wed, Oct 30, 2019   Day To Day (Hamstring) - The Knicks have listed Payton Jr. as OUT for Wednesday's game (Oct. 30) against the Magic.
>   Elfrid Payton   New York Knicks Thu, Oct 31, 2019   Day To Day (Hamstring) - Payton is listed as out for Friday's (Nov. 1) game against Boston.
<   Enes Kanter Boston Celtics  Wed, Oct 30, 2019   Day To Day (Left Knee) - The Celtics have listed Kanter as OUT for Wednesday's game (Oct. 30) against the Bucks.
>   Enes Kanter Boston Celtics  Thu, Oct 31, 2019   Day To Day (Left Knee) - The Celtics have listed Kanter as OUT for Friday's game (Nov. 1) against New York.
<   Evan Turner Atlanta Hawks   Wed, Oct 30, 2019   Day To Day (Achilles) - Turner is listed as doubtful for Thursday's (Oct. 31) game.
>   Evan Turner Atlanta Hawks   Thu, Oct 31, 2019   Out (Achilles) - Turner is listed as OUT for Thursday's (Oct. 31) game.
>   Frank Ntilikina New York Knicks Thu, Oct 31, 2019   Day To Day (Neck) - Ntilikina is listed as probable for Friday's (Nov. 1) game.
<   Harry Giles Sacramento Kings    Wed, Oct 30, 2019   Day To Day (Knee) - Giles III was inactive for Wednesday's game (Oct. 30) against the Hornets.
>   Harry Giles Sacramento Kings    Thu, Oct 31, 2019   Day To Day (Knee) - Giles III is listed as questionable for Friday's (Nov. 1) game.
<   Jaylen Brown    Boston Celtics  Wed, Oct 30, 2019   Day To Day (Illness) - Brown is listed as OUT for Wednesday's (Oct. 30) game against the Bucks.
>   Jaylen Brown    Boston Celtics  Thu, Oct 31, 2019   Day To Day (Illness) - Brown is listed as questionable for Friday's (Nov. 1) game against New York.
>   Justise Winslow Miami Heat  Thu, Oct 31, 2019   Out (Lower Back) - Miami Heat F Justise Winslow is OUT for Thursday's (Oct. 31) game against Atlanta with lower back stiffness.
>   Kawhi Leonard   Los Angeles Clippers    Thu, Oct 31, 2019   Out (Load Management) - Los Angeles Clippers F Kawhi Leonard is out for Thursday's (Oct. 31) against San Antonio.
>   Kyle Korver Milwaukee Bucks Thu, Oct 31, 2019   Out (Rest) - Korver is listed as OUT for Friday's (Nov. 1) game.
>   Matthew Dellavedova Cleveland Cavaliers Thu, Oct 31, 2019   Out (Personal) - Dellavedova is listed as OUT for Friday's (Nov. 1) game.
<   Myles Turner    Indiana Pacers  Wed, Oct 30, 2019   Day To Day (Sprained Right Ankle) - Turner left Wednesday's (October 30) game with a sprained right ankle.
>   Myles Turner    Indiana Pacers  Thu, Oct 31, 2019   Out (Sprained Right Ankle) - Turner is week-to-week with a sprained right ankle.
<   Rajon Rondo Los Angeles Lakers  Tue, Oct 29, 2019   Day To Day (Calf) - Rondo did not play in Tuesday's game (Oct. 29) against the Grizzlies.
>   Rajon Rondo Los Angeles Lakers  Thu, Oct 31, 2019   Day To Day (Calf) - Rondo is listed as out for Friday's (Nov. 1) game against Dallas.
<   Sekou Doumbouya Detroit Pistons Wed, Oct 30, 2019   Day To Day (Concussion) - The Pistons have listed Doumbouya as OUT for Wednesday's game (Oct. 30) against the Raptors.
>   Sekou Doumbouya Detroit Pistons Thu, Oct 31, 2019   Out (Concussion) - The Pistons have listed Doumbouya as OUT for Friday's (Nov. 1) game.
>   Will Barton Denver Nuggets  Thu, Oct 31, 2019   Out (Left Toe) - Denver Nuggets G Will Barton is OUT for Thursday's (Oct. 31) game against New Orleans with left toe inflammation.
```

Comment: Could you please do post sample expected output, along with your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem.

Comment: What's your field separator?

Comment: \t (tab) character

Comment: Maybe you want to [`join`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join) files. The `diff` is hard to parse, and I think doesn't show the intent of what you want to have. Please show excerpt from first file and from second file and then show the example expected output you want to have that shows what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little awk wrangling, I came up with this.
It counts all of the occurrences of the second field then prints those that equal 1.

```
awk -F $'\t' '{count[$2]++} count[$2] == 1'
```